# Why does Koh steal faces

Tags: tv, avatar-the-last-airbender, the-legend-of-korra

Why does Koh like to steal peoples faces when they show emotion of any sort. What does he gain from it beside people like Kuruk trying to kill him?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know that there is any more information beyond "spirits act by different rules."

It's like asking why Poseidon loves the sea: it's in his nature, and as a spirit, his nature is bound by rules that are more allegorical and symbolic than literal or practical.

Maybe they'll give more backstory on Koh later (I heard a rumor somewhere that we would meet him again in the next season), but for now I don't think there's any more information to be had.

Answer (score 8):

In the Avatar the Last Airbender comics "The Search Part 3" it is explained. Koh's mother was a spirit of faces; she would give new faces to people. Koh missed his mother so much that he would steal faces to fill the void of missing his mother.

[image]
<sub>[From MangaEden](http://www.mangaeden.com/en-manga/avatar-the-last-airbender---the-search/3/51/)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Its part of his "spirituaL physiology" and his spiteful nature. He may like to collect faces and wear different ones.